# recursive search and print most recent tar.gz file in each dir

Tags: files, find, tar

How to make a recursive loop through a path and get the latest created `tar.gz` file in each directory?

I want to run `tar -tvf file.tar.gz` on the latest created file in each directory

All the `tar.gz` files are located in the second directory level.. So the maxdepth of the loop is 2

This script will only print each directory

```
cd $base_dir
find . -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

The base dir is `/var/www/bak` and all the tar.gz files are located like

```
/var/www/bak/site1/www/file.tar.gz
/var/www/bak/site1/db/file.tar.gz
/var/www/bak/site2/www/file.tar.gz
/var/www/bak/site2/db/file.tar.gz
```

## update

```
find_tarballs (){
    cd $base_dir
    find . -name \*.tar.\* -execdir sh -c "echo -n \"\${PWD}/\"; ls -t *.tar.* | head -n 1" \; | sort -u -k1,1
}

filesize (){
    ls -lh $1 | awk -F " " {'print $5'}
}

output="$(find_tarballs)"
set -- $output
shift
for tarball; do
    echo "$tarball"
    if [ ${tarball##*.} = 'gz' ]; then
        list="$(tar -tzf $tarball)"
        echo "Filesize: $(filesize $tarball), Files: $(echo "$list" | wc -l)\n"
        echo 'Press ENTER to list files...'
        read key
        echo "$list"
    else
        echo "Filesize: $(filesize $tarball)"
    fi
    echo ''
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your paths don’t contain spaces or newlines:

```
find . -name \*.tar.\* -execdir sh -c "echo -n \"\${PWD} \"; ls -t *.tar.* | head -n 1" \; | sort -u -k1,1
```

will find all the tarballs, run the given shell snippet in each containing directory, and filter the result so that only one result is kept for each directory.

To view the tarballs’ contents, assuming their filenames also don’t contain spaces or newlines:

```
find . -name \*.tar.\* -execdir sh -c "echo -n \"\${PWD} \"; ls -t *.tar.* | head -n 1" \; | sort -u -k1,1 | tr ' ' / | xargs -n 1 tar tvf
```

will replace the space separating the path from the filename by “/”, and pass the result on to `xargs` which will run `tar tvf` on each file.

To prompt between each tarball, add `-p` to the `xargs` command:

```
find . -name \*.tar.\* -execdir sh -c "echo -n \"\${PWD} \"; ls -t *.tar.* | head -n 1" \; | sort -u -k1,1 | tr ' ' / | xargs -p -n 1 tar tvf
```

Comment: This script doesn't print all files..

Comment: in some subdirs only some of the sub-subdirs is parsed..

Comment: sorry.. its because some of the files are tar.xz

Comment: thats much better.. but how do I implement the `tar -tvf file.tar.*` part?

Comment: and is it possible to add a `read` after each `tar -tvf` with `press enter to see next file contents` ?

Comment: See the update, for both `tar tvf` and prompting.

Comment: Thanks but how to create a script that loop through the tarballs which is not a one-liner.. I need to simplify it.. Check me updated question.. I don't get why my script doesn't print all files.. I have just copy/pasted your `find` command into a function. Have just added a forward slash instead of a space between the path and the filename so the file is printed as the absolute path

Comment: have added some more logic to my script, but still can't make is show all files.. The command finds all files if I use your one-line command, but not if I put it into a function :(

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, in typical write-only fashion:

```
for dir (*/*(N/)) (){(($#)) && tar tvf $1} $dir/*.tar.gz(Nom[1])
```

- `for var (values) cmd`: shorter form of `for var in values; do cmd; done`
- `(N/)`, `(Nom[1])`: glob qualifiers

  - `N`: expands to nothing if there's no match (nullglob)
  - `/`: directories only
  - `om`: order by modification time (newest first)
  - `[1]`: first match only
- `(){...} args`: anonymous functions with its args.

With GNU tools (still making no assumption on what bytes file names may contain but traversing hidden directories and including hidden `tar.gz` files) and any Bourne-like shell, the equivalent could be:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -name '*.tar.gz' -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
  sort -zn | LC_ALL=C awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
    {match($0, ":((.*)/.*)", parts); newest[parts[2]] = parts[1]}
    END {for (dir in newest) print newest[dir]}' |
    xargs -r0n1 tar tvf
```

Comment: I only have native shell available

Comment: @clarkk, see edit with alternative for GNU systems.